# Trying to show the gaps of each seq on bio::Graphics after converting clustalw

Tags: sequence-alignment, perl

I want a box representing each sequence, positioned as they are in the alignment and with gaps shown as breaks in the each box.

I've been having trouble for a while with this and have been trying to get this on my own, but I can't. I'm trying to display the gaps using `Bio::Graphics` after retrieving my sequences from an alignment file.

I removed the exit portion. I was trying to format the code for this website and accidentally put the exit there. The input fill is a custalw file which is an alignment file with sequences on it. The sequences have "-" that represent gaps.

The command is `./aln.pl test-bioaln.aln > ll.png`
My expected output would be a .png file with sequences that are aligned and show gaps as a different color.

The input file is:

```
CLUSTAL W (1.81) multiple sequence alignment


JD1:1:102:1601:ORFJ00027      ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttct--c
94a:1:107:117:orf00001        ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttct-ac
118a:1:106:158122218:orf00020 ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttct-gc
B31:1:100:4091:ORFB0018       ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttctggc
72a:1:105:32:orf00022         ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttctggc
64b:1:110:473:orf00001        ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttctggc
29805:1:108:171:orf00001      ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttctggc
BOL26:1:111:60:orf00001       ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttctggc
CA-11.2A:1:109:33:orf00001    ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttctggc
WI91-23:1:112:493:orf00001    ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttctggc
297:1:103:411:ORFB00012       ttggatagattttatacaaagaaggtaataatgtataaacaacaatattttatttctggc
N40:1:101:1716:ORFK00021      ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttctggc
ZS7:1:113:22:orf00001         ------------------------------atgtataaacaacaatattttatttctggc
                                                            ******************************


JD1:1:102:1601:ORFJ00027      aaggtgcaaggtgttggttttagatttttcacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
94a:1:107:117:orf00001        aaggtacaaggtgttggttttagattttttacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
118a:1:106:158122218:orf00020 aaggtacaaggtgttggttttagattttttacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
B31:1:100:4091:ORFB0018       aaggtgcaaggtgttggttttagatttttcacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
72a:1:105:32:orf00022         aaggtacaaggtgttggttttagattttttacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
64b:1:110:473:orf00001        aaggtgcaaggtgttggttttagatttttcacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
29805:1:108:171:orf00001      aaggtgcaaggtgttggttttagatttttcacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
BOL26:1:111:60:orf00001       aaggtacaaggtgttggttttagattttttacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
CA-11.2A:1:109:33:orf00001    aaggtacaaggtgttggttttagattttttacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
WI91-23:1:112:493:orf00001    aaggtgcaaggtgttggttttagatttttcacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
297:1:103:411:ORFB00012       aaggtacaaggtgttggttttagattttttacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
N40:1:101:1716:ORFK00021      aaggtgcaaggtgttggttttagatttttcacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
ZS7:1:113:22:orf00001         aaggtacaaggtgttggttttagattttttacagagcaaatagcaaataatatgaaacta
                              ***** *********************** ******************************


JD1:1:102:1601:ORFJ00027      aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctcaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
94a:1:107:117:orf00001        aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctaaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
118a:1:106:158122218:orf00020 aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctaaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
B31:1:100:4091:ORFB0018       aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctcaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
72a:1:105:32:orf00022         aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctaaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
64b:1:110:473:orf00001        aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctcaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
29805:1:108:171:orf00001      aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctcaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
BOL26:1:111:60:orf00001       aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctcaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
CA-11.2A:1:109:33:orf00001    aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctaaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
WI91-23:1:112:493:orf00001    aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctcaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
297:1:103:411:ORFB00012       aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctaaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
N40:1:101:1716:ORFK00021      aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctcaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
ZS7:1:113:22:orf00001         aaaggatttgtaaaaaatctcaacgatggaagggtagaaattgtagctttctttaatact
                              ******************** ***************************************


JD1:1:102:1601:ORFJ00027      aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattaaa
94a:1:107:117:orf00001        aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattgaa
118a:1:106:158122218:orf00020 aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattgaa
B31:1:100:4091:ORFB0018       aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattaaa
72a:1:105:32:orf00022         aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattgaa
64b:1:110:473:orf00001        aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattaaa
29805:1:108:171:orf00001      aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattgaa
BOL26:1:111:60:orf00001       aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattaaa
CA-11.2A:1:109:33:orf00001    aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattgaa
WI91-23:1:112:493:orf00001    aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattgaa
297:1:103:411:ORFB00012       aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattgaa
N40:1:101:1716:ORFK00021      aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattgaa
ZS7:1:113:22:orf00001         aaagaacaaatgaaaaaatttgaaaaattattaaatgggaataagtattcaaacattaaa
                              ********************************************************* **


JD1:1:102:1601:ORFJ00027      aacattgaaaaaatagttttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
94a:1:107:117:orf00001        aacattgaaaaaatagttttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
118a:1:106:158122218:orf00020 aacattgaaaaaatagttttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
B31:1:100:4091:ORFB0018       aacattgaaaaaatagttttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
72a:1:105:32:orf00022         aacattgaaaaaatagttttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
64b:1:110:473:orf00001        aacattgaaaaaatagttttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
29805:1:108:171:orf00001      aacattgaaaaaatagctttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
BOL26:1:111:60:orf00001       aacattgaaaaaatagttttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
CA-11.2A:1:109:33:orf00001    aacattgaaaaaatagttttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
WI91-23:1:112:493:orf00001    aacattgaaaaaatagctttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
297:1:103:411:ORFB00012       aacattgaaaaaatagttttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
N40:1:101:1716:ORFK00021      aacattgaaaaaatagctttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
ZS7:1:113:22:orf00001         aacattgaaaaaatagttttagatgaaaattatccttttcaatttaatgattttaaaatt
                              **************** *******************************************


JD1:1:102:1601:ORFJ00027      tattat
94a:1:107:117:orf00001        tattat
118a:1:106:158122218:orf00020 tattat
B31:1:100:4091:ORFB0018       tattat
72a:1:105:32:orf00022         tattat
64b:1:110:473:orf00001        tattat
29805:1:108:171:orf00001      tattat
BOL26:1:111:60:orf00001       tattat
CA-11.2A:1:109:33:orf00001    tattat
WI91-23:1:112:493:orf00001    tattat
297:1:103:411:ORFB00012       tattat
N40:1:101:1716:ORFK00021      tattat
ZS7:1:113:22:orf00001         tattat
                              ******
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Bio::AlignIO;
use Bio::Graphics::Panel;

my $line = shift @ARGV;
my $in = Bio::AlignIO->new(-file=>$line,-format=>"clustalw");
while($aln = $in->next_aln()){
    foreach $seqobj($aln->each_seq()){
        my $seq = $seqobj->seq;
        my $id = $seqobj->id;
        my $length = $seqobj->length;
        my $seqobj = Bio::SeqFeature::Generic->new(-start =>1, -end=>$length,-display_name=>$id);
        push (@seq, $seqobj);
    }
    foreach $seq(@seq){
        my @features = $seq->get_SeqFeatures;
        my %sorted_features;
        for my $f (@features) {
            my $tag = "\-";
            push @{$sorted_features{$tag}},$f;
        }

        my $panel = Bio::Graphics::Panel->new(
            -length    => $seq->length,
            -key_style => 'between',
            -width     => 800,
            -pad_left  => 10,
            -pad_right => 10,
        );
        $panel->add_track(generic => Bio::SeqFeature::Generic->new(-start=>1,
                -end=>$seq->length),
            -glyph  => 'generic',
            -bgcolor => 'blue',
            -label  => 1,
        );

        my @colors = qw(cyan orange blue purple green chartreuse magenta yellow aqua);
        my $idx    = 0;
        for my $tag (sort keys my %sorted_features) {
            my $features = $sorted_features{$tag};
            $panel->add_track($features,
                -glyph    =>  'generic',
                -bgcolor  =>  $colors[$idx++ % @colors],
                -fgcolor  => 'black',
                -font2color => 'red',
                -key      => "${tag}s",
                -bump     => +1,
                -height   => 8,
                -label    => 1,
                -description => 1,
            );
        }
        print $panel->png;
        
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `$seq->get_SeqFeatures` never returns anything. I'm not sure why it doesn't since there should be features on it coming from the Bio::SimpleAlign object. Maybe I should set some new parameters?